# Example of conformal map that is not holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

From [an answer to my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190514/54809) I understand that if $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic then it is conformal.

I suppose that the other direction of the implication does not hold.

> Please would somebody give an (as simple as possible) example of a conformal
>   map that is not holomorphic?

The answer and the comment seem to contradict each other. I see no problem with the answer though so I'm inclined to think the comment is wrong. Could someone help me resolve this?

Comment: A map $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is conformal if and only if it is holomorphic and has non-zero derivative everywhere.

Comment: @WilliamStagner, unless it is orientation reversing; see answer or  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  f(z) = \bar{z} \; \; \; \;  $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you help me understand why it does not contradict the comment? Or why the comment is wrong?

Comment: @Anna, it does contradict the comment. Not sure what that guy is thinking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am still confused. If you look at [the Wiki article on conformal maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis) it first states that ''...[a map] is conformal if and only if it is holomorphic and its derivative is everywhere non-zero on $U$...'' and in the next sentence: ''If f is antiholomorphic (that is, the conjugate to a holomorphic function), it still preserves angles, but it reverses their orientation.'' I interpret this sentence to mean that an antiholomorphic map is conformal. (...)

Comment: (...) But this contradicts the previous sentence: the map $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is not holomorphic but since it is antiholomorphic it is conformal. Yet, due to the first sentence only holomorphic maps can be conformal. Please, would you tell me what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @Anna, what book are you using?

Comment: Freitag Busam.... I skipped forward to the definition and it seems they require it to preserve orientation, too. I also searched some more on the internet and now it seems that the map in you example is in fact anti-conformal. Since your answer helped me I will accept it nevertheless. My question has been answered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Anna, as a rule you stick with what your book says, when there are different definitions around. Note that the word "conformal" is used in differential geometry, and no assumption on orientation is typically made.

Comment: @Will Jagy the map you have considered preserves the magnitude of the angle but orientation of the angle gets reversed. I think these maps are called isogonal maps; conformal maps not only preserve the magnitude of the angle but also preserve the orientation of the angle , I guess. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.